# Uniform distribution and Gaussian distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

[image]

As the number of values sampled from the uniform distribution increases, the distribution of the mean tend towards a Gaussian. Why is that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem